# Read emails stored in Thunderbird with Java

Tags: java, email-attachments, thunderbird

I need a way to read the stored emails in Thunderbird with Java and retrieve attached files.

The problem is that I have an old FoxPro app that reads Zip files from a folder. The FoxPro used to retrieve those files from attachments into the emails in Outlook Express, when we installed Outlook 2007 this function of retrieve the files from Outlook didn't work anymore so it was replaced with a simple Java app (reading directly from the PST file). So now FoxPro app executes the Java app to retrieve those files.

Now I want to replace Outlook 2003 with Thunderbird and I want to read the emails from there.

IMPORTANT: The accounts are POP3 so I can't use IMAP to extract files directly from the email server.

There is a lib or something?

Answer (score 0):

As best I know there is no Java support, directly or by 3rd party library.  Having said that, I've looked at the way emails are persisted onto disk and you should be able to access those files directly with a Java app.  Attachments are stored inline and although I haven't tried to code an extraction app in Java, the structure and syntax of the attachments reminded me of the way attachments are stored in newsgroups (access via NNTP).

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird stores messages in mbox (loosely described in [RFC 4155](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4155)) files, with separate files for index/flags. [GNU JavaMail](https://www.gnu.org/software/classpathx/javamail/) should be able to read the mail store.  That's just the first implementation I found, it may not be that hard to write another one.